# What is the difference between 2X and R4 launch screens in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, ios7, ios6, launchimage

What do I do here, what is the difference between 2x and R4 launch images? Are they different resolutions, I made one with 640 x 1136 and it turns into an R4.

Answer (score 0):

4-inch iPhone running iOS 7 or later is an R4 where a 2x is if you are running pre ios 7

Comment: What are their respective resolutions? Do I need a separate image for both?

Comment: I believe the reason is due to the status bar changing over to being transparent in ios 7 you can get a true 640 x 1136

Comment: if you start the app with a status bar on top you may want to provide 2 images 2x at 640x1116 to account for the 20px black bar in ios 6 and previous and in ios 7 you will then use a r4 image of size 640x1136.  If you dont show a status bar on start you can use the same image